# How to extract a smooth skeleton from an image?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I am trying to segment AFM images containing DNA strands. In the image below you can see the orignal image, the segmented image and the skeletonized version.[image: Left: Original image, middle: segmented image, right: skeletonized image]. I wonder how I could improve my segmentation so that my image on the right contains less mini-branches, or by the same token that the image in the middle has more clearly defined edges and contours.

For reference, this is my code:

```
from skimage.morphology import remove_small_objects, dilation
from skimage.segmentation import clear_border
from skimage.filters import unsharp_mask, threshold_triangle, difference_of_gaussians
from skimage import exposure
import numpy as np

def preprocess_img(image, rescaling=False, sharpening=False):
    
    if rescaling: # rescale the intensity of the pixel values
        p2, p99 = np.percentile(image, (2, 99))
        image = exposure.rescale_intensity(image, out_range=(p2, p99))
            
    if sharpening and rescaling:
        image = unsharp_mask(image)
    
    thresh = threshold_triangle(image) # apply threshold
    mask = image > thresh
    mask = remove_small_objects(mask > 0)
    mask = dilation(mask)
    mask = clear_border(mask) # remove image border artifacts
    return mask
```

Comment: Typically a small opening before the skeleton will reduce the number of branches. There are also different implementations of the skeleton that tend to make more or fewer branches, which one are you using? Finally, you can prune short branches from the skeleton, but there are typically no ready-made functions for that.

Comment: Hello, I am using the default skeleton algorithm, but I will look for one that reduces the number of branches. Do you have any useful link at hand wrt pruning?

Comment: "the default skeleton algorithm"? There are many skeleton algorithms, and many implementations that all do things slightly differently. Are you using the one in skimage? `skimage.morphology.skeletonize`? This one implements two different algorithms. Try the other one too. There's a third algorithm implemented as `skimage.morphology.medial_axis`. Other libraries will have different algorithms too.

Comment: You can try to do this: On the skeleton, find the intersection points of the lines (matlab analogue of bwmorph 'majority' or Gaussian blur and threshold binarization), subtract these points from the skeleton, remove short lines remove_small_objects, return the intersection points back to the skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

My research group and I has been working on this problem (and a world of other AFM + DNA image analysis problems) through our software TopoStats (https://github.com/AFM-SPM/TopoStats.git).

For branch pruning, we apply a gaussian filter to the image before thresholding and obtaining molecule segmentations to reduce the spurious branches as much as possible. Then skeletonise the segmentation (while following the AFM height-map for better traces) and prune the branches using code within `skeletonize.py` (we're hoping to refactor this soon). But essentially, it separates branches and if they are below a threshold (<15% of total) their pixels are removed.

Here is an example of using our pruning function:

["Zhang" Scikit Image Skeletonisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozqs5.png)

["Joe"'s Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq2sG.png)

["Joe"'s Method Pruned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzLMU.png)